# pep8 warn about 8-space indent

Tags: python, pylint, pep8, pyflakes, flake8

This bit of code:

```
def foo():
        print("hello")
```

violates [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), which states

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

But neither the `pep8`, `pyflakes`, or `flake8` commands warn about it.

How can I get one of them to complain about this unpythonic code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pylint`](https://www.pylint.org/) would warn about this violation:

```
$ pylint test.py
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module test
W:  2, 0: Bad indentation. Found 8 spaces, expected 4 (bad-indentation)
```

Note that `pep8` would warn you only *if indentation [is not a multiple of four](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes)* (E111 error code).